# piping a cat command to c++ code multiple times

Tags: c++, pipe, istream

If I want to read a file multiple times with the command `./run in.txt`, there is a straight way,

0. `ofstream fin;`
1. `while (fin >> i) {…}`
2. `fin.clear(); fin.seekg(0);`
3. `while (fin >> i) {…}`

However, I want to pipe a zipped input file to the program. The command is

```
bzcat file.bz2 | ./run
```

and in the code, instead of `ofstream fin`, I have to use `std::cin`.

`while (std::cin >> i) {…}`

The loop terminates when bzcat sends the last line to the program. The question is, how can I go back to the start position and tell bzcat to please send the lines one more time (form first to the end) and I will catch them with `std::cin`?!

Comment: Did you try `bzcat file.bz2 file.bz2 | ./run`? There's nothing like a _backchannel_ you can use for communication with a piping program.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How will that help? That will just make the first loop read the file twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe contents are *consumed* as they are read, you need to retain those values in memory if you need a multipass algorithm, you can uncompress and run over the file or else you can split your program into multiple stages and run them one after the other:

```
// 1
std::vector<int> data;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(data));
// operate on data

#2
$ bunzip2 file.bz2 && ./run file.bz2

# 3
$ bzcat file.bz2 | ./stage1 | ./stage2 ...
```